# Odd reverse sorting and colors issue with charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

I have 2 charts on my page, both made using chartkick and google charts:

```
<%= pie_chart @articles.where(is_active: true).group(:category).count, colors: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"], legend: "right" %>
<%= column_chart @articles.where(is_active: true).group(:category).group_by_month(:date, last: 6).count, colors: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"], stacked: true %>
```

The problem I'm having is in first chart everything is working fine, but second one for some reason lists legend item in reverse order.

So for example I have first chart legend looking like this:

- 1 Stuff
- 2 Other stuff
- 3 Different stuff
- 4 Some stuff

and another exactly the same but upside down.

I am required to make colors of all categories consistent across all charts, and it doesn't help that on column chart there is condition "last 6 months", so some items may be missing if they didn't pop up in DB for last 6 months.

I have tried adding

```
.order('category desc')
```

but it didn't help much since all it did is changed order after colors have been applied already, so I had to also make a change to column chart

```
colors: ["violet", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red"]
```

It would work on paper if all categories were always present, but that's where root of the problem is. Also categories are named in format "1 Stuff" since it was a workaround to get them sort in desired order (not by alphabet).

Can anyone suggest any improvements/fixes?

Comment: Try with `.group_by_month(:date).last(6)`. If that wont give you the desire result, try ordering before group.

Comment: Got "undefined method `reverse_order_value' for #<Array:0xd969218>"

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version: 5.0.6